# String conversion contrasting output for primitive and string value

Tags: java, string

In the below mentioned program, Contrasting output for string and primitive value. How is this internally working??

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s1 = String.valueOf(99);
        String s2 = String.valueOf(99);
        System.out.println(s1==s2); //returns false, why??

         s1 = String.valueOf("99");
     s2 = String.valueOf("99");
        System.out.println(s1==s2);  //returns true, why??


}
}
```

Comment: @Jon I don't think this is really the appropriate dupe. I mean, sure, you don't compare string values like this; but that doesn't explain why the reference is the same in one case but not the other.

Comment: @AndyTurner: You could be right. Reopening.

Comment: Exactly this is not the duplicate question. The output varies depending on choosing String  or primitive type as parameter.

Answer (score 3):

`String.valueOf("99")` returns the same instance passed to it (since `valueOf(Object obj)` returns that `Object`'s `totString` and `String`'s `toString` returns `this`). Since both `"99"` Strings are the same instance (due to `String` pool), both calls to `String.valueOf("99")` return the same instance.

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}

/**
 * This object (which is already a string!) is itself returned.
 *
 * @return  the string itself.
 */
public String toString() {
    return this;
}
```

On the other hand, each call to `String.valueOf(99)` calls `Integer.toString(99)`, which produces a new `String` instance.

```
public static String valueOf(int i) {
    return Integer.toString(i);
}

public static String toString(int i) {
    if (i == Integer.MIN_VALUE)
        return "-2147483648";
    int size = (i < 0) ? stringSize(-i) + 1 : stringSize(i);
    char[] buf = new char[size];
    getChars(i, size, buf);
    return new String(buf, true);
}
```